# Best way to limit outgoing bandwidth in apache server (mirror)

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I will be setting up an apache foundation download mirror and open up to both public and private access. I would like to limit external access to about 650Mbps, but place no limits (preferably prioritize) on internal access. I would also like to serve clients as fast as possible when there is enough capacity to do so, but divide up bandwidth when there are many clients connected (hopefully evenly, but not necessary). On the side, the server will also be used for Ubuntu and Debian package mirroring. The webserver will only be serving static content and must use apache.

Currently configuration:
 
Apache version: Apache 2.4.18
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
 
CPU & RAM: preferably 2 core 4GB for now, but can expand to 4 core 32GB if needed
Apache Module: default

Options available ranked by ease of access:
- apache modules
- root access to the server running the apache server (open to software traffic shaping / rate limiting)
- very powerful and 99% idling Juniper EX4xxx series switch

Comment: Take a look at `tc`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working example based on tc and iptables.

**Step 1:**
 
Replace default pfifo_fast queue with PRIO queue.
PRIO queue is classfull queue and will allow us to attach filters later on to classify different types of traffic.

Check existing queue

```
tc -s qdisc ls dev eth0
```

Replace with PRIO. This will create 3 default bands.

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
```

Which can be visualized as below

```
      1:   root qdisc
     / | \ 
   /   |   \
   /   |   \
 1:1  1:2  1:3    classes
```

And now let's add classful queues. We will attach them to bands 1:1, 1:2 and 1:3

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: sfq
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2 handle 20: tbf rate 20kbit buffer 1600 limit 3000
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:3 handle 30: sfq
```

Which can be visualized as below

```
      1:   root qdisc
     / | \ 
   /   |   \
   /   |   \
 1:1  1:2  1:3    classes
  |    |    |
 10:  20:  30:    qdiscs    qdiscs
 sfq  tbf  sfq
  0    1    2     bands
```

Based on packet TOS traffic will go to

- 1:10 - Interactive traffic
- 1:20 - Interactive traffic
- 1:30 - Bulk traffic

But this is not exactly what we want considering that a few applications  will actually set TOS values
We want to classify traffic initiated from port 80 (sport=80) to go to 1:2 (which we shape and limit rate) and the rest of traffic to 1:1.
This way rest of the traffic won't have to wait for http traffic and will have a priority. Otherwise slow http traffic will block other non interactive traffic.

So how to do this?
We will mark our packets initiated from source port 80 with mark 2 via iptables and non http traffic with mark 1

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp --sport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 2          
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp ! --sport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

And we will use tc filter which will route packets marked with a tag to a particular band

```
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 handle 2 fw flowid 1:2    ### Send traffic from source port 80 to tbf queue
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 2 handle 1 fw flowid 1:1    ### Send all other traffic to sfq queue 1:1
```

And now we are ready to test. I will initiate download of CentOS iso from http server and at the same time I will initiate sftp transfer of the same image from same server. On the below picture we can see that while sftp transfer is about 13MB/s, http transfer is limited to 20kbit/s.

[image]

With this example band 1:3 is not even used.
 
So perhaps it was better to use tbf on band 1:3 and have 1:1 and 1:2 with sfq and default prioroties. However this was just a quick test and should be enough to hopefully clarify a bit better convoluted tc documenation.

Resources used:

- http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.classful.html
- http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.filters.html
- http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.adv-filter.html
- man iptables (on CentOS6, CentOS 7 has very reduced man for iptables
  since it's no longer default method to control firewall)

Answer (score 1):

A simple method could be to bring up multiple physical interfaces, each perhaps 1 Gbps. Put one on an external facing subnet and another on one facing internal.    mirror.example.com  is public accessible but mirror.corp.example.com is only on the LAN.

However, the limited by interface trick is not sufficient on virtual machines where the vNIC can go faster than the device it is emulating.

It also is much less fine of a control than you asked for.  You may need something more sophisticated if it is not safe to exceed the 650 Mbps target.

Answer (score 0):

Because apache's architecture spreads the load across many different processes/threads I don't think limiting/prioritising at the apache level is going to help.

I expect the best approach would be to use the traffic throttling/prioritising support in the linux kernel.

Unfortunately I haven't done this myself but I understand the go-to document on the subject is the linux advanced routing and traffic control howto.

I belive http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.html is the relavent chapter.

If you get this working please do come back and write an answer going into detail on how you got it to work.